# Find the number of terms from the sum of two different geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Notation:-  S[A, r, N] = sum to the 1st N terms of a geometric series whose 1st term is A and common ratio = r

Two different sums (A and B) are deposited every month for N months. They are compounded monthly at two different rates (known). The accumulated total is therefore S[A, r, N] + S[B, R, N] for some r and R (both known).

I want to find N such that S[A, r, N] + S[B, R, N] > K; where all quantities are known except N.

Is it possible to find N explicitly without going through the trial and error process?

Answer (score 0):

We have $$S[A,r,N] = A + Ar + ... + Ar^{n-1} = A\dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$
Similarly,$$S[B,R,N] = B\dfrac{1-R^n}{1-R}$$
Now we plug it into the inequality:
$$A\dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r} + B\dfrac{1-R^n}{1-R} > k$$
Let $y = \dfrac{A}{1-r}$, $z =\dfrac{B}{1-R}$ and $x = y + z$ , we have $x - yr^n - zR^n>k$ and thus $yr^n + zR^n < x-k$

Recognizing that $r$ and $R$ are known (and I assume they are less than $1$), the function on the left-hand side is decreasing when n is increasing. Yes, you can do some trial and error or plot the function to find the answer. I don't think that you can push this further with high school or first year undergrad math.

Comment: For interest compounded monthly at x% p.a., the amount for one period = A(1 + [x/12]%)^1. This means the r  (or R) is greater than one.